# MySQL check row exists but do not return it

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute a MySQL query that checks if a row exists in a table based on some criteria but does not return anything other than `true` or `false`.

Is it possible to do this? Something like:

`EXISTS in {table_name} WHERE id={some_id};`

Comment: please show your tables' structures, the query you tried and the eventual errors you found

Comment: select count(*) from x where y=1 and z=1. Application logic: if count == 1 return true else false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Sometable WHERE id = {Some_id})
```

[see documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just write the query, then use mysql_num_rows to check if it returned anything

```
if(mysql_num_rows($variable){
 // row was found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think deadman's answer should be.....

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Sometable WHERE id = {Some_id}) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```

(couldn't add comment as I'm a noob)

Comment: Hi Deadman. I must confess I only tried it in MS SQL, not MYSQL